# Can useState be used in conditional statment?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I tried to call set func of useState in if else statment but it does not assigned properly

```
const handleValidateAnswer = (id, choosedOption) => {
const temp = quizQuestion.filter((question) => {
    return id === question.id;
    });
    // console.log(temp[0].answer === choosedOption);
    if (temp[0].answer === choosedOption) {
      console.log('c');
      setAnswerStatus('correct');
    } else {
      console.log('i');
      setAnswerStatus('incorrect');
    }
    console.log(answerStatus);
  };
```

I tried to set the answerStatus to correct or incorrect but on initial rendering the state seems to be not working properly. Nothing is assigned when the handle function is invoked. What can I do?

Comment: This `console.log(answerStatus);` shows the old value, because changes to state are available in the next render cycle